# How to retrieve all products from a Smart Collection through Shopify API?

Tags: shopify

What's the best way to retrieve all products from a Smart Collection through Shopify API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Update: API version 2020-04

See [Codesmith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61898198/1367622) below. As of API version 2020-04, you can now use a smart collection id with the collections endpoint:

```
GET /admin/api/2020-04/collections/{collection_id}/products.json
```

See the [Collection API docs](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/collection?api[version]=2020-04) for more info.

---

### Pre-2020 solution

From the [SmartCollection](http://docs.shopify.com/api/smartcollection) page in the Shopify API docs:

> Smart Collections also use **collects** to connect a product to that smart collection.

And on the [Collects](http://docs.shopify.com/api/collect#index) page:

> **List only collects for a certain collection**
>
> ```
> GET /admin/collects.json?collection_id=841564295
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> {
>   "collects": [
>     {
>       "collection_id": 841564295,
>       "created_at": "2014-05-23T14:16:47-04:00",
>       "featured": false,
>       "id": 1071559648,
>       "product_id": 921728736,
>       "sort_value": "0000000001",
>       "updated_at": "2014-05-23T14:16:47-04:00",
>       "position": 1
>     },
>     ...
>   ]
> }
> ```

The collects contain the `product_id`s for each of the products in the collection with the specified `collection_id`.

Comment: There is another API available that may help others but does not work for me. There is a smart collection endpoint that appears to use a cursor to page through products.[Product Collections](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/collect)

`GET /admin/smart_collections/#{smart_collection_id}/products.json?only_sorted=all`

Comment: @Codesmith Thanks for the heads up! I've updated my answer with a link to yours.

Comment: Is there any way to do this in bulk in the post-2020 update? This new approach will slow things down significantly. For example 10 smart collections containing 1,000 products each, fetched 250 at a time = 40 API calls needed...

Answer (score 1):

### 2020 Update,

For the latest API (2020-04 as of now), you can simply use the `/collections/` endpoint, using the Smart Collection ID:

```
GET https://<shopname>.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-04/collections/<smart collection id>/products.json
```

More details can be found in Shopify's [Collection API Docs](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/collection?api[version]=2020-04).